# I cant save cookies in my code, can you please help me. Selenium, pickle, python

Tags: python, selenium, cookies

import pickle
import pprint

import time
from selenium import webdriver

class LinkedinBot:
def **init**(self, username, password):
""" Initialized Chromedriver, sets common urls, username and password for user """

```
    self.driver = webdriver.Chrome("/Users/andrey/Desktop/LinkedinBot-master/chromedriver")

    self.base_url = 'https://www.linkedin.com'
    self.login_url = self.base_url + '/login'
    self.feed_url = self.base_url + '/feed'

    self.username = username
    self.password = password

def _nav(self, url):
    self.driver.get(url)
    time.sleep(3)

def login(self, username, password):
    """ Login to LinkedIn account """
    self._nav(self.login_url)
    self.driver.find_element_by_id('username').send_keys(self.username)
    self.driver.find_element_by_id('password').send_keys(self.password)
    self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(text(), 'Sign in')]").click()

def save_cookies(driver, location):
    pickle.dump(driver.get_cookies("/Users/andrey/Desktop/LinkedinBot-master/chromedriver") , open("/Users/andrey/Desktop/LinkedinBot-master/cookies.txt","wb"))
```

Comment: I tried many methods but cookies just don't save in the text file. Or they save in some random Chinese. Please help.

Comment: @ZarakiKenpachi Well it kind of does, this is the solution, but for some preason I cant implement it in to my code. when I run it cookies dont save. Can you please look at last 2 lines of my code, maybe i sould implement it differently.

Comment: try to use `pickle.dump(self.driver.get_cookies(), open(....))`

Comment: Should I put it in dev or just leave it like this?     

def login(self, username, password):
        """ Login to LinkedIn account """
        self._nav(self.login_url)
        self.driver.find_element_by_id('username').send_keys(self.username)
        self.driver.find_element_by_id('password').send_keys(self.password)
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(text(), 'Sign in')]").click()
        pickle.dump(self.driver.get_cookies("/Users/andrey/Desktop/LinkedinBot-master/chromedriver") , open("/Users/andrey/Desktop/LinkedinBot-master/cookies.txt","wb"))

Comment: what you mean by `dev`? Don't add path to the driver inside get_cookies ...